# Variable has empty space in name. How to reference it correctly?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

How do I fix the syntax issue with the empty space between Campaign & Id?

```
%%[set @Campaign Id = __AdditionalEmailAttribute1=]%%
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be an exam question of some sort

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible to do in AMPscript. AMPscript variables cannot have spaces in them.

> Variable names must begin with @ and include at least one other
>   letter, number, or underscore. You cannot use spaces and commas in
>   variable names

ref:https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/languageElements.htm

I do not really see the need to require this as AMPscript variables are user defined and independent of field names.If you can expound on the issue you are trying to resolve, I can provide more info to help you find a new approach.

Comment: Hi @Gortonington, So Above statement is trying to add value of _AdditionalEmailAttribute1 (which you can set for an email in the platform) into Send Log DE during send time which has a column name [Campaign Id], yes It's with space. Now we know above code is not working so the only other option would be either change the column name to remove the space if AMPscript does not allow such behavior which could impact SQL queries already built and referring to this field or create a new column names Campaign_Id for future use and AMPscript.

Answer (score 1):

1. You set the name of an AMPscript variable, so you choose how it should be called and can set it to `CampaignID`
2. If a referenced column name has a space, put it in square brackets `[Campaign ID]`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Correct, in a ideal world, I would have set it as @Campaign_ID...however, there's already pre-built automatons in place to pass data from other field named [Campaign ID] which if changed can break other processes that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Can you explain more @Troy? AMPscript variables are independent of field names - they are user defined. So the name of your variable should not affect any process involving passing data from other fields.

Comment: @Troy where does the automation pass the data? An automation cannot “pass” any data directly into AMPscript..

Comment: Thanks Zuzana and Gortonigton for your Contribution. I just expanded the question a bit